# C++ Multiple virtual inheritance, classes share the same subobject

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I want to inherit 'x' from 'class B' and 'y' from 'class C' but both classes share the same 'A' subobject. Is there any solution?

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    protected:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        A() : x(10), y(10) {}
};

class B : virtual public A {
    public:
        B() {this->x = 20; this->y = 20;}
};

class C : virtual public A {
    public:
        C() {this->x = 30; this->y = 30;}
};

class D : public B, public C {
    public:
        D() {
            this->x = this->B::x;
            this->y = this->C::y;
            std::cout << "x = " << this->x << std::endl;
            std::cout << "y = " << this->y << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    D obj;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. Neither `B` nor `C` has an independent `x` or `y` to speak of, they both just have an `A` subobject.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you want something like this to work?

Comment: That’s what virtual inheritance means. If you want `B` and `C` to have distinct `A` sub-objects, don’t use virtual inheritance.

Comment: If you want to solve a practical problem, please describe it. If your issue is your way of thinking, please describe how you come to your conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the main problems that is solved by using composition over inheritance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Instead of inheriting from B and C your D object could contain instances of B and C. See the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    A() : x(10), y(10) {}
    
    int GetX() {
        return x;
    }
    
    int GetY() { 
        return y;
    }
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    B() {this->x = 20; this->y = 20;}
};

class C : virtual public A {
public:
    C() {this->x = 30; this->y = 30;}
};

class D {
public:
    D() {
        std::cout << "x = " << this->b.GetX() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y = " << this->c.GetY() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    B b;
    C c;
};

int main() {
    D obj;
    return 0;
}
```